# GNU G++ stops compiling after including D3D12 include paths (Using VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++, gnu, vscode-tasks, direct3d12

I am trying to get VSCode to compile DS3 Code, I have heard I needed these four include paths for D3D files to compile (to include d3d12.h):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\winrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt
```

Source: [I can't configure include paths in VSCode for D3D12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156684/i-cant-configure-include-paths-in-vscode-for-d3d12/52156776?noredirect=1#comment91450712_52156776)

So I did include them but now a simple file including windows.h does not compile any more.

The only thing in my only cpp is :

```
#define UNICODE // Necessary to use long chars in windows 
#define _UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

// include the basic windows header file
#include <windows.h>
```

Here is my vs code task and g++ command line:

```
 "command": "${env:Cygwin64BinPath}/g++.exe",
    "args": 
    [
        "-g", 
        "-o", "MassiveSteering", 
        "*.cpp", 
        "-D_DEBUG",
        "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/shared",
        "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/um",
        "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/winrt",
        "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/cppwinrt"
    ],
```

I get this in the console:

> Executing task: C:\cygwin64\bin/g++.exe -g -o MassiveSteering *.cpp -D_DEBUG '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/shared' '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/um' '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/winrt' '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/cppwinrt' <
>
> In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/shared/minwindef.h:182:0,
>
> from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/shared/windef.h:24,
>
> from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/um/windows.h:171,
>
> from main.cpp:7:
>
> C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17134.0/um/winnt.h:154:2: error: #error "No Target Architecture"
>
> error "No Target Architecture"

If I remove the four include paths I get no errors.
Something tells me that is not what I need to add to include d3d12.h